# How to get value of key based on another value using jolt transform

Tags: json, jolt

**Input**:

```json
{
  "color": "green",
  "red": "1",
  "green": "2",
  "blue": "3"
}
```

**Expected output**:

```json
{
  "color": "green",
  "green": "2",
}
```

Based on the value of key `"color"`, the respective key value pair needs to be returned in output.

Tried a bunch of jolt specs, nested @‘s but not able to figure out this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "color": {
        "*": {
          "@2,&": "&" // "&" returns the value of color(eg.green), 
                      // "@2,&" returns the value of green(eg.2) 
                      // and they're matched reversely(eg."green":"2")
        },
        "@": "&" // returns the key-value pair of the top level key, 
                 // eg. "color":"green" 
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]